# Putting a Github Pages site onto a custom domain causes css to go missing?

Tags: dns, github

I have a website for a education project. It lives at [this github repo](https://github.com/joereddington/whitewaterwriters-site/).  I tested it at https://equalitytime.github.io/whitewaterwriters-site/ and it worked as expected, but then I changed it to a custom domain and now it looks [like this](https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/).

If I [fork it to my personal github](https://github.com/joereddington/whitewaterwriters-site/settings) and then serve it again, it [looks normal again](https://joereddington.github.io/whitewaterwriters-site/)

What is going on?

My settings for the custom domain are:

[image]

Compared to the forked (working) repo:

[image]

...and the DNS records I edited to make the custom domain work are:

[image]

My questions are:

- Why is the site working differently?
- How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `baseurl` in your `_config.yml` needs to be cleared, since you are no longer serving from a subfolder.

I've submitted a pull request that fixes it.

Comment: You absolute superstar!

Answer (score 1):

I want to add my experience because the `baseurl` was empty to begin with. However the `url` in the `_config.yml` file had the original `example.github.io` as the address. I changed it to the apex domain name that I owned and configured in Github. For reference, I was using the **academic** theme by LeNPaul in Github.